# Unblock from timed receive on mutex unlock

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, synchronization, posix

I have a thread that attempts to read stuff from a message queue using a timed receive function. The thread also has a mutex which acts as an indicator of when it needs to exit (for example, the application has been closed): initially the mutex is locked, and when it's unlocked (somewhere else), the thread needs to stop.

I want to do a timed receive in such a way that it also unblocks when the mutex is unlocked. So when we're requested to stop we do that immediately without waiting for the timed receive timeout.

In Windows, I can achieve that with overlapped IO and WaitForMultipleObjects(). An overlapped read on a named pipe returns me an object, and then I wait on both that object and the mutex at the same time.

Is there any way to do it in POSIX?

Comment: Can you not just post some message to the queue to wake up the thread and so make it notice some 'terminate' boolean?   On non-trivial OS, if the thread does not need to close before app termination, you shold not try to terminate it explicitly unless there is an overriding requirement to do so.

Comment: @MartinJames Yeah that could actually work.

Comment: C is not C++ is not C! Pick a language.

Comment: @Olaf What? This applies to either.

Comment: Please informa yourself. C and C++ are **different** languages. If you code in C++ C-**style** that does 1) not imply identical semantics and 2) is very bad coding style. Similar the other way. If someone told you different, he apparently does not know at least one of the languages well enough.

Comment: @Olaf This question is mainly about the POSIX API, which you use in both C and C++.

Comment: The POSIX API is C-only. So that is a C question. You even do not show any C++ code. Also, there are OOP wrappers for the synchronisation primitives. You do not clarify what you actually do.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways. Probably the simplest is to use a boolean value that gets set to `true` when the thread should stop. Protect the boolean with a mutex and have the thread check it periodically.

A better solution is to use an atomic boolean. Most likely, you're using a platform that has them, either from C++-11, as compiler intrinsics, or some other way.

Comment: If there is only one writer and many readers, the mutex shouldn't even be necessary.

Comment: @Ctx POSIX has an [explicit requirement](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_11) that a memory location cannot be modified in one thread while it is, or might be, accessed in another. So you definitely either need a mutex or some form of atomic operation.

Comment: My question is not how to check a mutex periodically, it is how to exit from a timed receive as soon as a mutex unlocks, even if this occurs before the timeout. Let's say you have a timed receive with a timeout of 1 hour. 5 minutes in the mutex unlocks. I want the timed receive to return immediately after this occurs and not wait the remaining 55 mins.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Does not apply to atomic datatypes such as a bool. Atomic datatypes are just there to enable lock-free programming

Comment: @IvanMolodetskikh That depends on exactly what kind of receive you have. For example, if it's on a TCP connection, use `shutdown` to cause the `read` to abort. Or you might want to reduce the timeout, check the bool, and then retry to shutdown more quickly. It's very specific to the exact use case.

Comment: @Ctx I'm pretty sure you're just making that up. I cited an authoritative source -- the documentation for the threading standard he is following.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm talking about message queues (like POSIX message queues or XSI message queues etc). I guess the only way to do this particular thing is to receive with smaller timeouts and check the mutex in-between. Another way would be to post a message into the queue to make the timed receive return (as noted in the comment to the question), and I think I have found yet another way to use mq_notify() in case of POSIX message queues.

Comment: @IvanMolodetskikh Those are all good methods. As I said, it's very specific to the exact use case. If clean shutdown is required, it should be designed in from the beginning, not added at the end as an afterthought. You have my sympathy if you have to add clean shutdown to someone else's code. (Using signals or `pthread_cancel` might be an option too.)